# Why is there arbitrary code in this EventHandler example from the C# Programming Guide?

Tags: c#, events, delegates, event-handling

I am trying to better understand an example from the C# Programming Guide documentation.  I have watched it execute step-by-step in Visual Studio, and read the documentation for clues.

It uses a generic EventHandler delegate.  Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DotNetEvents
{
    class Program
    {

    class CustomEventArgs : EventArgs
        {
            public CustomEventArgs(string s)
            {
                message = s;
            }
            private string message;

            public string Message
            {
                get { return message; }
                set { message = value; }
            }

        }

        class Publisher
        {
            public event EventHandler<CustomEventArgs> RaiseCustomEvent;

            public void DoSomething()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Did something");
            }

            protected virtual void OnRaiseCustomEvent(CustomEventArgs e)
            {
                EventHandler<CustomEventArgs> handler = RaiseCustomEvent;

                if(handler != null)
                {
                    e.Message += $" at {DateTime.Now}";

                    handler(this, e);
                }
            }
        }

        class Subscriber
        {
            private string id;
            public Subscriber(string ID, Publisher pub)
            {
                id = ID;
                pub.RaiseCustomEvent += HandleCustomEvent;
            }

           void HandleCustomEvent(object sender, CustomEventArgs e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(id + " received this message: {0}", e.Message);
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Publisher pub = new Publisher();
            Subscriber sub1 = new Subscriber("sub1", pub);
            Subscriber sub2 = new Subscriber("sub2", pub);

            pub.DoSomething();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Why does it seem like the following line is completely arbitrary:

```
protected virtual void OnRaiseCustomEvent(CustomEventArgs e)
            {
                EventHandler<CustomEventArgs> handler = RaiseCustomEvent;

                if(handler != null)
                {
                    e.Message += $" at {DateTime.Now}";

                    handler(this, e);
                }
            }
```

Nothing in this method affects the outcome if commented out.  Additionally, I commented out these lines & it didn't seem to affect anything:

```
//pub.RaiseCustomEvent += HandleCustomEvent;
```

and,

```
/* void HandleCustomEvent(object sender, CustomEventArgs e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(id + " received this message: {0}", e.Message);
            } */
```

It would help a lot to understand why this stuff is added in.  Thanks.  For reference, here is the page I got the code from. I removed some of its comments since I was typing it rather than copying & pasting.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-publish-events-that-conform-to-net-framework-guidelines

Comment: Because it shows you how to create an event? more specificallly one of your own format and choices

Comment: Sure the outcome is identical, as there´s no code that actually **raises** the event, whch is by calling `OnRaiseCustomEvent`. You have to call that method somewhere in order to have any effect in your clioent-code, which registers the `HandleCustomEvent`-method.

Comment: I'd suggest starting with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/how-to-raise-and-consume-events . Focus on what `Add` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `pub.RaiseCustomEvent += HandleCustomEvent` this code in itself does absoluetely nothing except to register a method to an event. When you don´t ever **raise** that event, that method (we call it an event-handler) will surely never be executed.

In your code you would raise that event by calling `OnRaiseCustomEvent` somewhere in your `Publisher`-class. However we can´t know when that event should actually be raised.

For example you could raise the event whenever some client called `DoSomething` on any `Publisher`-instance. Then you would call `OnRaiseCustomEvent` from within your `DoSomething`-method:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    OnRaiseCustomEvent(new CustomEventArgs("I did something"));
    Console.WriteLine("Did something");
}
```

This when you call `pub.DoSomething` the event is raised and your event-handler (`HandleCustomEvent`) would be called.